# export json from mysql as nested json

Tags: python, mysql, json, google-cloud-firestore

I currently run a query that exports the json in the following format

```
[
    {
        "id" : 1,
        "name" : "Sin movimiento",
        "points" : 1,
        "lower_limit" : 0,
        "deleted" : 0
    },
    {
        "id" : 2,
        "name" : "Más de 25 km/h",
        "points" : 3,
        "lower_limit" : 25,
        "deleted" : 0
    }
]
```

However in order to import the data correctly to firebase, all the other detalils such as name, points, lower_limit, deleted should be nested inside the id in this way:

```
    [   
       {

    "1": {
          "name": "Sin movimiento",
          "points":1,
          etc...
         }
      },

    {

    "2": {
    "name": "Más de 25 km/h",
    etc
         } 
    } 
 ]
```

How would i go and accomplish this? is it possible to write a query using Mysql 5.6? or should i write a python script for this? any guidance appreciated.

Comment: This would definitely be easier in Python than MySQL.

Comment: Loop through the results of the query. Get the value of the `id` element of the dictionary, delete it from the dictionary, then make the dictionary the value of a new dictionary whose key is the id.

Answer (score 0):

I would have done it in Python rather than MySql.

```
[{s['id'] : {k : v for k, v in s.items() if k != 'id'}} for s in data]
```

Where data is your dictionary (or JSON data).

```
data = [
    {
        "id" : 1,
        "name" : "Sin movimiento",
        "points" : 1,
        "lower_limit" : 0,
        "deleted" : 0
    },
    {
        "id" : 2,
        "name" : "Más de 25 km/h",
        "points" : 3,
        "lower_limit" : 25,
        "deleted" : 0
    }
]
```